"Page Not Found" when trying to access a multipage site deployed on Netlify
I'm running a multipage website site and deploy it on Netlify. I source files on GitHub, and Netlify deploys it.
Netlify reports that the site is live (deploy log enclosed at the bottom), but when I'm trying to view my site, all I see is a Netlify error message:
Page Not found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
← Back to our site
What could be the reason?
My GitHub Repo: https://github.com/Serhii-Bolhovskyi/green-spaces
My deploy settings:
Repository: https://github.com/Serhii-Bolhovskyi/green-spaces
Build command: npm run build
Publish directory: src
Production branch: main
Branch deploys: Deploy only the production branch and its deploy previews
Public deploy logs: Logs are public

When I try to change Publish directory: src/pages I receive a page which contains only index.html without any styles and applied TailwindCss.


it seems your website works correctly now, I just tried it
